# accordion jquery not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I want to use accordion from jquery ui (https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible) in my mvc Home/Index view but can't get it to work.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                collapsible: true
            });
        });
  </script>


<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any error on console??

Comment: no, just displaying as text nothing happens when headers are selected

Comment: This is a same example as in jQuery UI Demo site, everything works there, check your references to js and css files, be sure you have added all css references, it is important for jQuery UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are including jQuery's JS file, and that it is before jQuery UI's JS file.

```
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```